# Limited access for postgreSQL user

Tags: postgresql

is it possible to create PostgreSQL user so that he can connect and see only  one specific database? So that he could only see one database (he couldn't see the others). Ideally, I could also set the visibility of the tables in the database.
I create user like this:

```
create user user with encrypted password 'password';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE db TO user;
```

although I have given the user connect privilege to only one database, he can see all other databases :(

Answer (score 0):

By default the `connect` privilege to every database is granted to the role `public`, so you need to run:

```
revoke connect on database ... from public;
```

for all other databases. Make sure you grant connect back to existing users.

Another option is to restrict connections for this specific user through [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

Comment: If it is as you write, I must admit that it is not well solved. If I have 200 databases on one instance, do I have to apply REVOKE CONNECT for each of them ?

Comment: If you don't want to control it through GRANTs, then use `pg_hba.conf`

Comment: It makes no sense. Then in mysql it is much more conveniently handled. In mysql I give access to the specific database and I can only see one database. I can't see the other databases. In postgres, I see all of them by default.

Comment: Shrug. Different database products behave differently. If you revoke connect from public on the template database then all future database will also have no connect privilege for public. And you still can control access on a per database per user bases through `pg_hba.conf`. Additionally: what MySQL calls a "database" is actually a schema as far as the SQL standard is concerned.

Comment: So tell me how to configure access so the user can see only one database. It doesn't matter if it's through the pg_hba.conf file or privileges. Give me an example.

Comment: "see only one database" is  a different requirement than "can only connect to one database".